# Не пойму, почему не работает метод установки

Tags: javascript

```js
let p = {
    x: 2,
    y: 3,
    get r() {
        return Math.hypot(this.x, this.y);
    },
    set r(newValue) {
        oldValue = Math.hypot(this.x, this.y);
        let ratio = newValue / oldValue;
        this.x *= ratio;
        this.y *= ratio;
    },
};

p.r = 10;
console.log(p.r);
```

Почему то когда я задаю значение параметру метода установки, то последующие его операции не выполняются, а просто выводится значение которое я задал. Или я может просто не так задаю значение параметру или не так вызываю метод установки. Помогите пожалуйста, буду очень благодарен

Comment: Что должно выводится?

Comment: Без задания значения параметру метода установки должно выводиться: 2.8284271247461903
А если задавать значение параметру установки(в данном случае 10) должно выводиться: приблизительно 12.747548783980413

Comment: Как получаются *2.8284271247461903* и *12.747548783980413*?

Comment: То как мне кажется, если без задания значение параметру метода установки должны выполняться начальные значения свойств, т.е 3 и 4. А если задаю значение параметру метода установки, то должна выполнять сначала операция квадратного корня из суммы квадратов, после деление значения параметра на получившийся квадратный корень и умножение начальных значений x и y на получившееся значение в ratio, и последующий их вывод в методе получения

Comment: Какие начальные значения?

Comment: Данные результаты получаются путем выполнения операций, которые я описал в комментарии выше.

Comment: начальные значения: 
x: 2,
y: 3

Comment: *2* и *3* или *3* и *4*?

Comment: 2 и 3. Извиняюсь, просто в момент написания перепутал.

Comment: Весь код рабочий - метод установки работает. Ошибка, я думаю, в проверке в вашей голове. Поместите проверку в вопрос, тогда можно будет понять что именно не так.

Comment: Объясните тогда, почему при задании значения параметру метода установки у меня не выполняются последующие операции, а выводится просто 10? Код рабочий, я может неправильно задаю значение параметру или неправильно вызываю метод установки

Comment: Ладно, спасибо, буду разбираться

Comment: Вы говорите "установи норму вектора 10". Потом вы спрашиваете "какая теперь норма вектора?" и получаете ответ "10". Это правильно. Если вы считаете что должно быть по-другому, ваше мнение с объяснением лучше вписать в вопрос.

Comment: Может он правильно выводит, но я не пойму для чего тогда нужны операции данного метода. Данная задачи из книги Дэвида Флэнагана и тут почему то не приводится вариант решения с заданием значения параметру.

Comment: @Nikon в целом сеттеры и геттеры нужны для дополнительного контроля над данными. В частности в сеттерах можно сделать доп операции или проверки значения.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое

Answer (score 2):

Все работает верно. В этом можно убедиться выведя объект полностью.

Так как `r` - это вычисляемое свойство, при его установке изменяются внутренние поля. Значения их вычисляются так, чтобы при получении `r` результат было тем, что передается в сеттер.

```js
let p = {
    x: 2,
    y: 3,
    get r() {
        return Math.hypot(this.x, this.y);
    },
    set r(newValue) {
        oldValue = Math.hypot(this.x, this.y);
        let ratio = newValue / oldValue;
        this.x *= ratio;
        this.y *= ratio;
    },
};


console.log(p);
p.r = 10;
console.log(p);
```